# ftp file upload reporting ok but directory empty - pureftp centos cpanel

Tags: centos, subdomain, ftp

its a whm centos install with pure-ftp. When I ftp into the server with the normal account I get the to the root successfully: /home/user_name

I'm trying to set up a dev domain on the server, so created the account: dev@domain.com, in cpanel its there successfully, I pointed it to /home/user_name/subdomains/dev, also created the subdomain and can view it successfully.

The problem is when I log in with the new dev@domain.com account, it logs in successfully, but shows me a blank 'ls -l' listing. I can upload files using both filezilla and netbeans, all reports success, but when I navigate to /home/user_name/subdomains/dev its empty.

Also sestatus:

```
SELinux status:                 disabled
```

Log files:
/var/log/messages:

```
Mar  1 05:23:23 server pure-ftpd: (?@ip-address) [INFO] New connection from ip-address
Mar  1 05:23:23 server pure-ftpd: (?@ip-address) [INFO] dev@domain.com is now logged in
Mar  1 05:23:24 server pure-ftpd: (dev@domain.com@ip-address) [NOTICE] /home/user-name/subodmains/dev//test.php.new uploaded  (110 bytes, 0.77KB/sec)
Mar  1 05:23:24 server pure-ftpd: (dev@domain.com@ip-address) [NOTICE] File successfully renamed or moved: [test.php.new]->[test.php]
Mar  1 05:23:24 server pure-ftpd: (dev@domain.com@ip-address) [INFO] Logout.
```

also the log file at:

```
/usr/local/apache/domlogs/user_name
```

for the dev@domain.com account is empty.

Been at this since last night, and I'm completely lost, any help or direction would be great. cheers

Comment: Can you see the files if you log in with your normal account? Have you checked the permissions for the new users?

Comment: yep. if I log in with the normal account I can put/get files ok.

where would I check permissions for the new user?

Comment: chown dev  /home/user_name/subdomains/dev

Comment: no joy. `chown: `dev': invalid user` tried with with `username:dev` as well but didn't work either.

Comment: isn't the ftp accounts and system accounts different? don't think i should be creating linux users for each ftp account I want. I'll try creating a new ftp account with the same root dir as the working default account

Comment: created a new ftp user, and set the default dir of `doc_root/username` Uploading to this works. Might have found a solution... remove subdomain from cpanel, and create new account in whm => http://forums.cpanel.net/f34/subdomain-ftp-log-cannot-view-folders-111169.html

Comment: solved. The problem was down purely to my own stupidity. Embarassed to say it but gonna have to, i called the folder for the ftp account 'subodaims' instead of 'subdomains'. Due to the time lost on this by me i would appreciate it if you didn't tell anyone ;) but thanks a million for your help @boburub - cheers